BibTex: Reduce names to "Author 1 et al" in my .bst
I'm very new to LaTeX and need to use it for my academic work.
I was given a template I need to use and need to change the way the in-text citation works. I already figured out, that I need to change the FUNCTION {format.names} part of my .bst file, but don't know how exactly, since I don't want to mess up any other settings. The settings look currently like this:
{ 's :=
  #1 'nameptr :=
  s num.names$ 'numnames :=
  numnames 'namesleft :=
    { namesleft #0 > }
    { nameptr #1 >
%ivo welch changed. original was
%        { s nameptr "{f.~}{vv~}{ll}{, jj}" format.name$ 't := }
%        { s nameptr "{vv~}{ll}{, jj}{, f.}" format.name$ 't := }
        { s nameptr "{ff~}{vv~}{ll}{, jj}" format.name$ 't := }
        { s nameptr "{vv~}{ll}{, jj}{, ff}" format.name$ 't := }
      if$
      nameptr #1 >
        {
          namesleft #1 >
            { ", " * t * }
            {
              " " *
              t "others" =
                { " et~al." * }
                { " \textmd{and} " * t * }  %%%KCB(8-11-95): added \sc
              if$
            }
          if$
        }
        't
      if$
      nameptr #1 + 'nameptr :=
      namesleft #1 - 'namesleft :=
    }
  while$
} 


Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Please add a short, but compilable test file which allows us to reproduce the problem. It should include a class, the necessary packages and a document environment.

Is this bst file available online? Please also tell us how you load the natbib citation management package.

Yes the .bst is available here: http://faculty.haas.berkeley.edu/stanton/texintro/
and I import natbib as \usepackage{natbib}

I see several bst files on that webpage. Which one in particular are you interested in?

Please also clarify the scope of the "Reduce names to 'Author 1 et al' " formatting objective. Specifically, should it apply to all publications with two or more authors, or just to publications with three or more authors?

Sorry, I meant the 'Journal of Finance' style. But it seems like the file is not available  anymore... Where can I post the full code of the .bst here ?
I want all publication with more than one author to be shown as " Author one et al.".
